# The count value is not getting saved to newly declared variable

Tags: c, performance-testing, loadrunner

Have captured the `web_reg_save_param` and the count value is not getting saved to newly declared variable.

I have tried by declaring in global as well as locally.

```
int ExsistingGoal;
char ParamName[50]; 
int i;

// {"id":"49F2DC5064524DC3962EE783959CA211","name":"Legacy Protection 1",


web_reg_save_param("c_ExsistingGoal","LB= 
     {\"id\":\"","RB=\",\"name\":\"","ORD=All",LAST);


web_add_header("Authorization:","Bearer {c_Token05}");

web_add_header("X-request-ID","8dd9e540-fa3c-11e9-8c6b-47e84a716a57");


web_url("goals_3", 
    "URL={pURL02}/wms/v1/plan/plans/{c_PlanID}/goals?entityId= {c_EntityID}", 
    "TargetFrame=", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=application/json", 
    "Referer={pURL02}/mwp/select-goals", 
    "Snapshot=t79.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);


ExsistingGoal= atoi(lr_eval_string("{c_ExsistingGoal_count}"));
```

`c_ExsistingGoal_count` this values should get saved to the variable 
  `ExsistingGoal`.

But currently it's displaying some random value:`153500656`

Comment: You should start tear apart that instruction. What does `lr_eval_string` return? Where should `c_ExsistingGoal_count` come from? Is that first "s" a typo? Do you mean `c_ExistingGoal_count`? BTW:  Is anything except the last statement relevant to your problem?

Comment: c_ExsistingGoal -- > values is getting captured from the request web_url("goals_3"

web_reg_save_param(); should save all the possible values with the same Left and right boundary as i used Ord=all

O/P count value should get saved in the decalred variable "ExsistingGoal".
(lr_eval_string("{c_ExsistingGoal_count}") should return value: 3

Comment: I see a lot of "should". Did you verify any of your assumptions? What does `lr_eval_string` return? Does it return a string, or `NULL`?

Comment: I can answer some of Gerhardh's questions, the array of values is seeded by the LaodRunner service function, web_reg_save_param(), which acts a sieve through which the HTML is poured, with the LB and RB conditions defining what gets captured.   This then results in an array of values, ORD=ALL reference,  <paramname>_1 through n.  The value of n is stored in <paramname>_count.  The paramname in this case is c_ExsistingGoal.   My best guess is that the conditionals are not resulting in an array population and it is returning an address instead of a value

Comment: When you turn on logging for parameter data, do you see the value being populated as part of the array before you get to the conversion and assignment to a C variable

Answer (score 0):

In my POV, James Pulley answered this question.
If you use ORD=ALL in web_reg_save_param function. LR will save count number which meet correlation condition in <paramname>_count. If You get the value of 153500656 in this case, it means the web_reg_save_param function correlated 153500656 items in array.

```
//You can use the 1st correlated item
ExsistingGoal_1= atoi(lr_eval_string("{c_ExsistingGoal_1"));

//You can use the 153500656th correlated item
ExsistingGoal_153500656= atoi(lr_eval_string("{c_ExsistingGoal_153500656"));

//In frequently usage, you can judge flow by <paramname>_count, and output the specific <paramname>_<count>. 
if(atoi(lr_eval_string("{c_ExsistingGoal_count}"))>0)
    {
        lr_output_message("c_ExsistingGoal_1=%s",lr_eval_string("{c_ExsistingGoal_1}"));        
        lr_end_transaction("Correlation Pass",LR_AUTO);
    }
    else
    {
        lr_end_transaction("Correlation Fail",LR_FAIL);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below function it will help you -

```
web_reg_save_param("ExsistingGoal","LB=someText", "RB=\")", "Ord=ALL",LAST);

lr_output_message("PC:%d",atoi(lr_eval_string("{ExsistingGoal_count}")));
```